# Trying to fill a html table with json

Tags: javascript, json, html-table

I apologies for the silly question, I'm a beginner and am quite confused with the mix of Javascript, jQuery, Ajax...

I have have a json file, located in json/bdd.json :

```
{
"donnees" : [

        {
            "id": 1,
            "date": "01/01/2020",
            "name": "Pâques",
            "tag": "Fête",
            "long": "5min",
            "icon":"<i class='fab fa-itunes-note'>"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "date": "01/10/2020",
            "name": "Anniversaire",
            "tag": "Fête",
            "long": "21min",
            "icon":"<i class='fab fa-itunes-note'>"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "date": "01/03/2020",
            "name": "Conférence",
            "tag": "Travail",
            "long": "56min",
            "icon":"<i class='far fa-file-alt'></i>"
        }
]}
```

I want to fill an html table like this :

```
<table class="table">
  <thead class="black white-text">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Nom</th>
      <th scope="col">Tag</th>
      <th scope="col">durée</th>
      <th scope="col"><i class="fab fa-itunes-note"></i> / <i class="far fa-file-alt"></i></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table-body">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Edit : problem solved, it works with this current code :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $.getJSON('json/bdd.json', function(i, donnees) { 

  $.each(i.donnees, function (index, element) {

  let row = (`<tr>
  <td scope="col">${element.id}</td>
  <td scope="col">${element.date}</td>
  <td scope="col">${element.name}</td>
  <td scope="col">${element.tag}</td>
  <td scope="col">${element.long}</td>
  <td scope="col">${element.icon}</td>
</tr>`);


$('#table-body').append(row);
 });

 });

 });
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hi, take a look to this plugin.
https://www.datatables.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate your table using `$.each()` inside getJSON callback.

```
$.getJSON('json/bdd.json', function(i, donnees) {

  // Add this line
  donnees = JSON.parse(donnees);

  $.each(donnees, function(index, element) {
    let row = jQuery(`<tr>
      <th scope="col">${element.id}</th>
      <th scope="col">${element.date}</th>
      <th scope="col">${element.name}</th>
      <th scope="col">${element.tag}</th>
      <th scope="col">${element.length}</th>
      <th scope="col">${element.icon}</th>
    </tr>`);

    $('#table-body').append(row);
  });

});
```

Comment: I tried that, but have an error message : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in success" ...

Comment: Thats probably becasue $.each is trying to iterate over a string. You need parse JSON before iteration. I updated my answer.

Comment: I've already tried, but have an error message : "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0"

Comment: Ok. Remove that line and try to change this `$.each(donnees,` to his `$.each(donnees.donnees,`

Comment: Yes ! I just changed a bit what you told me : $each(i.donnees), and it worked ! Thank you :) I'll edit my code.

Comment: If it solved your question then please tick this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do need to loop through the object array. 
My personal preference would be a forEach loop

E.g.:
`donnees.forEach((row) => ... // Append a row to the table )`

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: Did you try this?

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
     $.getJSON('json/bdd.json', function(i, donnees) { 

        $.each(i, function (index, element) {
            var row = '<tr>'+
                            '<td scope="col">'+element.id+'</td>'+
                            '<td scope="col">'+element.date+'</td>'+
                            '<td scope="col">'+element.name+'</td>'+
                            '<td scope="col">'+element.tag+'</td>'+
                            '<td scope="col">'+element.long+'</td>'+
                            '<td scope="col">'+element.icon+'</td>'+
                        '</tr>';

            $('#table-body').prepend(row);
        });

     });
  });
```